# Update table entity with a variable not explicit JSON

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I compose a string of the properties I want to update on a table storage entity in the jsonString variable. The value of jsonString is like "prop001": "false","prop002": "false". Where there are a variable number of properties.

I was hoping to use it like the image below illustrates but it does not allow this as a validator insists on valid JSON.

[image]

Is there aniother way to achivee what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following workaround:

1. [Initialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-variables-store-values?tabs=consumption#initialize-variable) / [set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-variables-store-values?tabs=consumption#set-variable) a `String` variable using the input that currently doesn't work for you (because it isn't recognized as JSON)
2. In the `Entity` field of your action insert the following [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language#expressions): `json(variables('name_of_your_variable'))`

The field value in the code will look like this:
[image]

Hopefully, that helps.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to update on a table storage entity in the jsonString variable. The value of jsonString is like "prop001": "false","prop002": "false". Where there are a variable number of properties.

You can add the Json string variable in the following way-

1. Create the entity in Table storage as shown below.

[image]

2. Post this action, add ***Merge Entity (V2)*** action as like below.

[image]

I have the below value in JsonString Variable.

[image]

I am able to get the expected output.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I am using the In App connectors on a private VNet and Merge Entity does not appear to be available

Comment: Can you please share your workflow?

Comment: I would like to know which connector you are using

Comment: {
  "type": "ServiceProvider",
  "inputs": {
    "parameters": {
      "tableName": "jobstatus",
      "entity": {
        "PartitionKey": "@{utcNow('yyyy')}",
        "RowKey": "@{variables('clientTrackingId')}"
      }
    },
    "serviceProviderConfiguration": {
      "connectionName": "azureTables",
      "operationId": "upsertEntity",
      "serviceProviderId": "/serviceProviders/azureTables"
    }
  },
  "runAfter": {
    "For_each_widget_add_a_property_to_entity_on_table_storage": [
      "SUCCEEDED"
    ]
  }
}

Comment: Above details looks like the code view. I would like to know which connector you are using? It will be easier for me to help you if you can share the screenshot of your design diagram